# Populating a UILabel from a NSString

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsstring, uilabel

wow weird !!, I am passing a value NSString from my prepare for segue to another class. Ok, the string has a value and when passed to my -(void) the value is still there. I have an IBOutlet UILabel connected but the below code does not populate the UILabel. I am logging this from the void method.

2016-09-01 14:21:56.839 ApiAIDemo[1263:586780] **The msgString has this in it** {
    speech = "The Moon is Earth's only permanent natural satellite. It is the fifth largest natural satellite in the Solar System, and the largest among planetary satellites relative to the size of the planet that it orbits. It is the second-densest satellite among those whose densities are known.";
}

Here is my property.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *myMsgLabel;

-(void)passedMsgFromVoicButtonVC:(NSString *)msgString{

    **NSLog(@"The msgString has this in it %@",msgString);**

    self.myMsgLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",msgString];

    NSLog(@"BELOW the msgLabel has this in it %@",_myMsgLabel.text);

}
```

Comment: where do you call passedMsg method ?

Comment: I call it from a different class like this below, also FYI the NSLog statement also proves there is a value.   - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
     NSLog(@"In the prepareForSegue the _msgLabel has this %@",_myResult);
     Msgview *msg = segue.destinationViewController;
     [msg passedMsgFromVoicButtonVC:_myResult];
    }

Comment: if you are able to see _myMSGlabel.txt then try printing the label frame.

Comment: NSStringFromCGRect(_myMsgLabel.frame)

Comment: Couldn't help noticing you've never marked an answer correct on SO.  It's a good habit to help others who read the posts later and to encourage others to help you.

Comment: The NSSTringFromCGRect is {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}

Comment: I am sorry but that is not true I always tick up on correct answers.

Comment: looks like the frame is 0, hence you are unable to see it, try to set the frame for tha label.

Comment: Strange thing is that I took away the IBOutlet and added the UILabel as a subview and .... The text is there..                Very odd.

Comment: Yes the label shows it does not have a height or width but it was set in the UI..

Comment: Tick up/down is how you rate questions and answers.  For answers to questions asked by *you* there is a more important gesture: the check mark icon just underneath the down-tick arrow marks the answer as the one you found to be correct and applied.

Comment: Also, @PhillipMills has the correct answer in my opinion.  If you agree, try marking it correct (in addition to up-voting).

Answer (score 3):

Create a non-outlet property in your controller to hold the string that's being passed in from the segue.  Then update the outlet in `viewDidLoad`.

The problem is that segues are called before iOS has set up the controller's UI correctly.

Comment: @JohnZ - pease use the check mark directly under the vote count.